# MYSQL key column does not exist

Tags: mysql, database

I need assistance, my 'Key column' says it does not exist when it clearly does.

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLISHER ( 
 LISHER_ID INT PRIMARYKEY, 
 LISHER_NAME VARCHAR(5NNULL, 
 LISHER_ADDRESS VARCHAR(NOT NULL, 
 LISHER_PHONE VARCHAR(5) NULL,
 LISHER_EMAIL VARCHAR(4) NULL);
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question into something like this because nobody can use this any more. If you think it's not helpful for anyone you can delete it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the original question was removed and replaced by a "thanks".

Answer (score 2):

The column you name in the `FOREIGN KEY` clause has to exist in the table on which you're defining the constraint - in this case, it has to be a column in the table `CONTRACT`.

At a guess, I think you probably want

```
CREATE TABLE CONTRACT (
  ...
  CONSTRAINT FK_CONTRACT_PUBLICATION FOREIGN KEY (PUBLICATION_PUB_ID)
    REFERENCES PUBLICATION (PUB_ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have two mistakes, both from what appears to be copy/paste. In your CONTRACT table, you named the column PUBLICATION_PUB_ID, but in your index definition and your foreign key constraint you tried to reference it as just PUB_ID.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE CONTRACT (
            -> CON_NUMBER INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            -> CON_STARTDATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
            -> CON_ENDDATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
            -> PUBLICATION_PUB_ID INT NOT NULL,
            -> INDEX PUBLICATION (PUBLICATION_PUB_ID),
            -> CONSTRAINT FK_CONTRACT_PUBLICATION FOREIGN KEY (PUBLICATION_PUB_ID) REFERENCES PUBLICATION (PUB_ID)) ;
```